# C++ Setter member function with const reference causes "read access violation" exception at run-time

Tags: c++

How do I create a class setter member function that uses const reference as its parameters? I wrote the definition of the setter of how I thought it should be, but upon running it breaks and returns a "read access violation" exception.

```
//==== Start of Main.cpp ====
int main()
{
std::string temp="test";
NodeData thingy;

thingy.setname(temp);

return 0;
}
//==== End of Main.cpp ====
```

```
//==== Start of NodeData.hpp====
class NodeData
{
public:
void setname(const std::string &newName);

private:
std::string *mpName;
};
//==== End of NodeData.hpp ====
```

```
//==== Start of NodeData.cpp====
void NodeData::setname(const std::string &newName)
{
*(this->mpName)=newName;//this here is what causes compiler error I think
//mpName=newName; Doesn't work because "no suitable conversion function from "const std::string" to "std::string *" exists"
}
```

[image]

Comment: you should declare mpName as std::string mpName not as a pointer or declare it is as a reference. you are dereferencing the mpName even though it is not pointing anywhere

Comment: Are you sure you're getting a compilation error and not a runtime error?

Comment: @StephenNewell yep pretty sure. This is exactly what happens upon compiling: https://i.imgur.com/y7m6bFy.png

Comment: That is not a compile-time, but a runtime error.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer is to not use a pointer in your class.

```
class NodeData
{
public:
    void setname(const std::string &newName);

private:
    std::string mpName;
};

void NodeData::setname(const std::string &newName)
{
    mpName = newName;
}
```

Newbies often use pointers inappropriately, did you have a good reason for using a pointer in your class?